# Need advice on best way to access database in iPhone app

Tags: ios, database, xcode, methodology

So I am fairly new to iOS development and have decide to create a project of my own. This app is using Parse as it's backend. I know that it is better to have all the database calls in one class, but am unsure of the best way to do it. So far I have two options:

1. Create separate .h and .m files and put all database accessors there as static methods
2. Create base .h and .m files (that inherit from UIViewController) and put all the calls there. Then derive all my other view controllers in the app from this one.

Which of these two options is better? Or is there a better way to do this than these two options?

Answer (score 0):

While this is purely opinion based I would argue for solution 1. This creates a good separation of code and makes it clear where the database methods are located both when looking at a view controller. Compare `[DBConnector performDatabaseMethod]` to `[self performDatabaseMethod]` the second one seems weird and out of place if `self` is a `UIViewController` subclass.

Another option is using a singleton database accessor which you access using `[[DBConnector sharedInstance] performMethod]` where `sharedInstance` looks something like this.

```
+ (id)sharedInstance {
    static DBConnector *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}
```

Comment: That what i went with a first, but then I realized, what if I need to take control of the screen during a call (for example bring up a rotating loading icon). That would be easier achieved with the derived method, but then again, that is only one positive thing.

Comment: What about doing that just before the call, making the call on a background thread and using a delegate method when the call is done, hiding the spinner (This of course requires an instance of the connector)?

Comment: Yea, its possible, just would be a little more complicated. 
Also, why would you need an instance of the connector?

Comment: Since a purely static connector doesn't have any state, as such it can't know which delegate it should pass the callback to.

Comment: Does this not mean then my methods can't be static anymore? Cause if I'm creating an instance of the connector, it destroys the purpose of having static methods.

Comment: Yes, in that case you would have to solve it with a singleton pattern. I can provide an example if you like.

Comment: That would be very helpful